# Css-Grid, Grid-auto-rows dosen't work and the page it's not reponsive as it should

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm following a course on CSS Grid, and I don't understand why my mockup doesn't behave as it's shown in the course. I have 12 div, and if I reduce the page's width, despite the fact that I have in my CSS the option to auto-generate rows, it stops behave responsively.

This is my index.html

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffeead;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.container>div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #88d8b0;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.container>div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, and why is not responsive?

Thank you.

Comment: Try Flex instead of grid.

Comment: your code seems to work fine, what is the issue?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Thank you for your time. The issue is that if I try to reduce the width of the page I should get to the point where there is only one column and each box as is own row. As you would aspect to see a responsive website on a SmartPhone. However when I try to reduce the width of the page it works until 600px, and then stops. I hope I've been clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: this is not the case when testing your code here ... it works fine even under 600px

Comment: You also set `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));` which means to break into a single element on each row, you need less than 200px  of width.left from margin and paddings. Which browser are you using for testing ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I'm using Chrome, and it's up to date. I'm running Linux-Mint, but even on a Local Server if I try to use my SmartPhone to access it, the page isn't responsive and everithing is really small.